# Storage pool configuration for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure-virtual-machine, alwayson

We are in the middle of building a new SQL Server 2017 always-on cluster in Azure VM. The data disk layout of VM are as follows

```
TempDb      :   2    Azure Disk Read Cache    
TempDBLog   :   1    Azure Disk No Cache    
UserDB      :   3  Azure Disk   Read Cache    
UserDBLog   :   2  Azure Disk   No Cache
```

My plan is to create a multiple storage pool, i.e TempDB storage pool with 2 TempDB disk, UserDB storage pool with 3 User db Azure Disk.

However,according to the link
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance.md (First paragraph under Data Disk)

> If you are using a disk striping technique, such as Storage Spaces,
>   you achieve optimal performance by having two pools, one for the log
>   file(s) and the other for the data files. However, if you plan to use
>   SQL Server Failover Cluster Instances (FCI), you must configure one
>   pool.

Is this applicable to Always-On or just applicable to  shared storage FCI. 
Please guide me, Please share good articles/docs for reference.

Thanks